# Why I couldn't handle an exception thrown from a destructor outside of it?

Tags: c++, exception

I've read in C++ primer 5th edition ch18 on Exception Handling that a destructor usually should not throw an exception like STL containers and if it should, that thrown expression should be wrapped in a try-catch block (a catch must handle that exception).

- I've tried this for understanding purpose:

  ```
    struct Foo{
        Foo(){
            std::cout << "Foo()\n";
        }
        ~Foo(){
            std::cout << "~Foo()\n";
            throw "exception thrown from Foo::~Foo()\n";
            std::cout << "Back in Foo::~Foo()\n";
        }
    };


    int main(){

        try{
            Foo f{};
            Foo* pFoo = new Foo{};
            delete pFoo; // normally exception caught here nad handled by the following catch
        }
        catch(char const* const& cp){
            std::cout << cp << '\n';
        }

        std::cout << '\n';
    }
  ```
- IMHO `Foo`'s Destructor should not here throw that exception because a handler outside that Destructor can never catch that exception; because destructor is invoked  whenever an object goes out of scope and a try-catch block is always inside a block, in other words the destructor is called after a try-catch blcok.
- But as we know we can call a destructor prematurely for example calling it explicitly or deleting a pointer of a class/struct type that points to a valid dynamic memory. So in this case we can call that destructor inside a `try-block` which normally can be handled by the corresponding handler.
- But my program always calls `terminate()` (as a sign of unhandled exception) and I get the warning:

`warning: throw will always call 'terminate' [-wterminate]`.

- AS you can see I am invoking the `Foo` destructor inside `try-block` in `main`: `delete Foo`. The same I can do if I wrote: `f.~Foo();`.
- So can someone explain the reason behind that? Thank you!

Comment: My earlier, and now deleted comment was a mistake. You placed your try/catch in the wrong place. Destructors should generally not throw. If they must, it must be handled *within* the destructor itself. Exceptions are for exceptional circumstances. Exceptional circumstances tend to exclude destructors because destructors **will** do their jobs.

Comment: Since C++11 exceptions in destructors are forbidden unless the destructor is explicitly declared as [`noexcept(false)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec). Destructors are implicitly declared as `noexcept(true)`.

Comment: FYI: [C++ FAQ: How can I handle a destructor that fails?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions#dtors-shouldnt-throw): _Write a message to a log-file. Terminate the process. Or call Aunt Tilda. But do not throw an exception!_

Comment: As for a reason why exceptions in destructors are bad, lets say some other code have thrown an exception. While uwinding the call-stack from that initial exception the destruction of a local object throws a second nested exception, ***that you can not catch***.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Do you mean if I declare it `noexcept(false)` then the code will work fine?

Comment: @Maestro Well "fine" I don't know, but `std::terminate` will not automatically be called because of that.

Comment: Side note: g++ 6 or higher gives a nice hint: *note: in C++11 destructors default to 'noexcept'*. Poking around with godbolt, it looks like clang 5+ gives a similar note.

Comment: is it possible that you just misunderstood "and if it should, that thrown expression should be wrapped in a try-catch block (a catch must handle that exception)." ? If an exception is thrown in a destructor you should catch it inside the destructor. Wrapping the destructor call inside a try-catch is not a solution

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818: I meant wrapping it in "try-block" inside the destructor not the destructor itself.

Comment: then I don't get it. In yuor "I tried this..." there is no try-catch in the constructor

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818: I didn't say "constructor" but "destructor".

Comment: sorry, typo. There is no try-catch in your destructor

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the recommendation:

> a destructor usually should not throw an exception like STL containers and if it should, that thrown expression should be wrapped in a try-catch block (a catch must handle that exception).

In other words, it says:

You should not throw an exception from a destructor.

Now the question arises what one should do if the destructor is:

```
~Bar() {  
   do_something();
}
```

and `do_something()` might throw an exception. In this case the recommendation is to catch the exception and handle it:

```
~Bar() {
    try {
        do_something();
    } catch(...) {
       // handle exception, eg write a log message
       // but do not retrow it or a different one!
    }
}
```

Now there is no way the exception leaves the destructor.

---

As you discovered, catching the exception outside of the destructor does not help to solve the general problem, because here:

```
 try{
          Foo f{};
          Foo* pFoo = new Foo{};
          delete pFoo; // normally exception caught here nad handled by the following catch
      }
```

The call to `delete pFoo;` throws an exception. During stack unwinding `Foo f{};` will be destroyed and another exception will be thrown from the destructor. If an exception is thrown during stack-unwinding `std::terminate` will be called. And the way to avoid that to happen is to not throw exceptions from destructors.

Comment: A constructor also can raise an exception but why it is OK from ctor and not from dtor?

Comment: @Maestro because throwing an exception does trigger destructors getting called, and if they throw again you have a problem. Throwing an exception rarely triggers the call to a constructor.

Comment: @Maestro you throw an exception when a) you cannot handle the problem at the place where it occured and b) the problem can be handeled somewhere up the call stack. With destrcutors b) does not hold, because in the worst case nobody can catch the exception and `std::terminate` is called. Thats why you should reconsider a) and handle the exception directly in the destructor. With constructors thats not the case.

Comment: OK now I've got it correctly! Because as you've said: when pFoo is deleted its dtor is called which throws without handling it so control leaves Foo's dtor searching for a handler in the call chain. so try block is being left thus all local objects are destroyed so here f dtor is called. but it again throws so we have 2 exceptions during stack unwinding which invoke 'terminate'. if only one object is there and dtor is noexcept(false) then it looks ok but so dangerous. this problem doesn't trigger ctors because they are not called automatically like dtors. Thank you very much!